# How to compare two string using RegEx

Tags: regex, string, string-comparison

I have a collection in the MongoDB which has list of URLs like below.

[image: List of URLs in mongoCollection]

In my business logic for some requirements, I want to check whether the called URL is matching with any of the records in the DB records.

like req.originalUrl i get suppose

```
/logistics/initiator/5ee7a0be36acdc46ae0576d6/users
```

But in the above URL obviously, I'm getting the actual Id -- **5ee7a0be36acdc46ae0576d6**

**What i tried:**

I tried manually concatinating the req.baseUrl and req.route.path but that still gives me the below string

```
/logistics/initiator/:initiator/users
```

which is again incomparable.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the ID with `\{\w+\}`, and use that as a regular expression to match against the `url` column in the table. So the regexp should be `/logistics/initiator/\{\w+\}/users`.